# Azure data factory access policies assigment using azure powershell inline script in devops pipline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, paas

There is one task which is simple and easily achieved using cloud shell, I need to give access to my
    Datafactory get, set in access policies 
    commands

```
    $objectid = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "BDAZE1ENRG01" -Name 
    "BDAZE1INDF03").Identity.PrincipalId                          
    Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName "BDAZE1ENKV01" -PermissionsToKeys get,list - 
    PermissionsToSecrets get,list -ObjectId $objectid
```

Devops task screen shot 
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

JEpOB.png

error is devops log
    [image]

powershell version 3.1.0 task version inline script 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the command `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`, it will call the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getobjectsbyobjectids-get-objects-from-a-list-of-object-ids--) to validate the `$objectid` you passed. In could shell, it uses the credential of your user account, it works means your user account has the permission. In devops, the service principal has no permission to do that by default.

To solve the issue, the easiest way is to use the `-BypassObjectIdValidation` parameter like below, then it will work fine.

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName "joykeyvault" -PermissionsToKeys get,list -PermissionsToSecrets get,list -ObjectId $objectid -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

[image]

Of course there is another way, just grant the application permission in Azure AD Graph like below for the AD App of your devops connection. (Must be `Application` type permission in `Azure Active Directory Graph`, not `Microsoft Graph`, don't forget to click `Grant admin consent` button)

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy many thanks this thing BypassObjectIdValidation works for me.